# jquery ajax request - empty request div output

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

first, pls. forgive me formatting errors and lack of knowledge. I am a total jquery and ajax noob.

I retrieve data via ajax query based on the crossdomain jquery plugin from [james padolsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery). The received data is put into a span ID. When I get empty data, I would like to display a "no data received message" in the same span, instead of the empty result.

my code looks like this:

```
<span id="data"></span>

<script>

    $.ajax({

        url: "http://www.theurliloadfrom.com",
        type: 'GET',

        success: function(res) {
            var theData = $(res.responseText).find('#extdata').text();
            $("#data").html(theData);
        },

        error: function(){
            $("#data").html("There was an error");
        }

    });

</script>
```

Someone could help?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check by using below condition

```
<script>



$.ajax({

    url: "http://www.theurliloadfrom.com",
    type: 'GET',

    success: function(res) {
          if(res != undefined)
           {
            var theData = $(res.responseText).find('#extdata').text();
            $("#data").html(theData);
       }
       else
       {
        $("#data").html("no data received message");
       }
       },

    error: function(){
        $("#data").html("There was an error");
    }

});

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I now understand how to check against the condition if the request delivers undefined. sorrily it still doesn't work for me.